# unable to create dynamic form

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
    import  getComponent  from "./component_selecter"
    
    const MBTI_Firob = props => {
      const elementse = [
        { name: "mbti", title: "MBTI"    },
        { name: "wiredup", title: "Wired-Up "  },
         
      ];
      return (
        <Stack spacing={2} direction="column">
          <Paper>
            <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
              MBTI & FiroB
            </Typography>
          </Paper>
          {elementse.map(element => (
    
           getComponent(element.type);
             
          ))}
         
           
        </Stack>
      );
    };

export default MBTI_Firob;
```

**component_selecter**

```
import { Box, FormControlLabel, FormControl, FormLabel, RadioGroup, Radio } from "@mui/material";

 function getComponent(componentType: string):string {
  var component = {
    "SELECT": (
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>  </FormLabel>
        <RadioGroup row aria-labelledby="demo-row-radio-buttons-group-label" name="row-radio-buttons-group">
          <FormControlLabel value="no" control={<Radio />} label="No" />
          <FormControlLabel value="yes" control={<Radio />} label="Yes" />
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
    )
  };

  return component[componentType];
}


export default { getComponent };
```

in the above  code when the getComponetnt function is called I get the following error.What I try do to is generate a dynamic form according to the values saved in the ***elementse*** object array

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature
```